# Ui-router, unknown provider issue

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I get the following error "Module 'ui-router' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument."

[image]

What is weird is that I have installed ui-router using npm install and it is in my packages.json file.

I presume the error is because I have misspelled the module name?

Any help is really appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: Post your code, not image of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states **you either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it**. In this case you misspelled it, it should be `ui.router` not `ui-router`.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);
```

The only other cause of this error, after spelling it correctly, would be that you **forgot to load it**. Fix this by including a reference to the library.

Comment: Hi papakia, I get the same error but with ui.router when I change it?

Comment: Are you including the ui router file??

Comment: In the index.html file? Do I need to add a <script> tag to the ui-router node module?

Comment: Yes you need to add it before this code is executed because it is a [dependency](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122606/discussion-between-swimmingg-and-papakia).

Comment: Just as a note to people, if you get unhelpful error messages it can be because you are using minified versions of angular. So bear this in mind.